# WS-Security UsernameToken with Apache CXF

Tags: java, soap, cxf

I have a java application that interacts with a SOAP service. I used the WSDL to generate a java client via CXF, but I need to authenticate my calls using ws-security. I am looking for a code-only way to do this, and I don't have any xml configurations. This is what I have tried:

```
Map ctx = ((BindingProvider)port).getRequestContext();
ctx.put("ws-security.username", "joe");
ctx.put("ws-security.password", "joespassword");
port.makeSoapCall();
```

But I get a parse error for invalid WS-Security header. What is the right way to do this?

In SOAP UI, I can do this easily by right-clicking the soap header, clicking "Add WSS UsernameToken", and selecting "Password Text"

Answer (score 7):

You are using WS-SecurityPolicy as per the code you shared. How about using WS-Security only and sending across the usernametoken using WSS4JOutInterceptor?

Check the section "**Adding the interceptors via the API**" in apache cfx ws-security guide here : http://cxf.apache.org/docs/ws-security.html

This is what needs to be done as per the above apache cxf documenation above. You might only need the out interceptor path.

*On the client side, you can obtain a reference to the CXF endpoint using the ClientProxy helper:*

```
import org.apache.cxf.frontend.ClientProxy;
...

GreeterService gs = new GreeterService();
Greeter greeter = gs.getGreeterPort();
...
org.apache.cxf.endpoint.Client client = ClientProxy.getClient(greeter);
org.apache.cxf.endpoint.Endpoint cxfEndpoint = client.getEndpoint();
```

*Now you're ready to add the interceptors:*

```
import org.apache.cxf.ws.security.wss4j.WSS4JInInterceptor;
import org.apache.cxf.ws.security.wss4j.WSS4JOutInterceptor;
...

Map<String,Object> inProps = new HashMap<String,Object>();
... // how to configure the properties is outlined below;

WSS4JInInterceptor wssIn = new WSS4JInInterceptor(inProps);
cxfEndpoint.getInInterceptors().add(wssIn);

Map<String,Object> outProps = new HashMap<String,Object>();
outProps.put("action", "UsernameToken Timestamp");
outProps.put("passwordType", "PasswordDigest"); //remove this line if want to use plain text password
outProps.put("user", "abcd");
outProps.put("passwordCallbackClass", "demo.wssec.client.UTPasswordCallback");

WSS4JOutInterceptor wssOut = new WSS4JOutInterceptor(outProps);
cxfEndpoint.getOutInterceptors().add(wssOut);
```

You will need to write password callback class (UTPasswordCallback) in the example above.

Apache cxf has a complete sample for UserName token here: http://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/cxf/trunk/distribution/src/main/release/samples/ws_security/ut/

From the above link browse to client folder (src/main/java/demo/wssec/client) for user name token and UTPasswordCallback code.

EDIT: If your wsdl expects password as plain text then just remove this line from the code:
                outProps.put("passwordType", "PasswordDigest");

Answer (score 0):

You could take a look at the "ws-security/ut" demo that ships with CXF, this shows how to add a UsernameToken programmatically. Here is the client code:

https://github.com/apache/cxf/blob/master/distribution/src/main/release/samples/ws_security/ut/src/main/java/demo/wssec/client/Client.java

Colm.