# CXF UsernameToken Issue

Tags: java, web-services, cxf, wss

I'm trying to add an UsernameToken wss header to my ws Client. 
The client implements javax.xml.ws.Service and has been generated through WSDL2Java CFX 3.1.4

Since the wsdl contains

```
<wsp:Policy xmlns:wsu="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd" xmlns:wsse="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd" xmlns:wsp="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2004/09/policy" xmlns:sp="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/07/securitypolicy" wsu:Id="UsernameTokenPolicy">

     <sp:UsernameToken>
        <wsp:Policy>
          <sp:WssUsernameToken10/>
          <sp:HashPassword/>
        </wsp:Policy>
     </sp:UsernameToken>

 </wsp:Policy>
```

Usernametoken header must be added. Searching a bit I've found out that this is simple as

```
((BindingProvider)soapClient).getRequestContext().put("ws-security.username", usr);
((BindingProvider)soapClient).getRequestContext().put("ws-security.password", psw);
```

By the way when I try to perform a call I get the following error:

```
These policy alternatives can not be satisfied: 
{http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/07/securitypolicy}UsernameToken: Password hashing policy not enforced
```

Any advice?
Thank you.

P.S. I've already checked for similar post in stack overflow, but if I try a differente approach like the one suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26599983/ws-security-usernametoken-with-apache-cxf) I got a different error:

```
Interceptor for XXXX has thrown exception, unwinding now
org.apache.cxf.ws.policy.PolicyException: No username available
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the [cxf-documentation](http://cxf.apache.org/docs/security-configuration.html) states

> From Apache CXF 3.1.0, the WS-SecurityPolicy and the XML Security
>   (JAX-RS) components in CXF share a common set of configuration tags.

So you shouldn't use `ws-security.username` and `ws-security.password` but `security.username` and `security.password`

Also be sure that ***cxf-rt-ws-policy*** and ***cxf-rt-ws-security*** modules are available on the classpath so ws-policy will automatically be enabled, thus taking care of hashing the password, i.e. calculate the correct password digest.